How do I use the same java script for 2 different elements in html
Right now only the first mp4 works with this, the second one doesnt. Honestly the stylesheet part is not that important, I don't mind if it gets cut out cause it's hard to do or something. I don't have the skills to implement other solutions that other have found so I am asking myself.
index.html:
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="video-container">
          <video src="honda/honda adv.mp4"></video>
          <div class="hover-text active"><b>Autoturisme</b></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <script src="main1.js"></script>


      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="video-container">
          <video src="honda/honda engine.mp4"></video>
          <div class="hover-text active"><b>Motoare</b></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <script src="main2.js"></script>

style1.css (same code as style2.css at this moment):
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  top:-350px;
  left: -550px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
}

.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-container .hover-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
    transform: translate(calc(-50% - 24px), -50%);
    background: #ff0019;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 50px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
  }
  
  .video-container .hover-text.active {
    opacity: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

main1.js (same code as main2.js):
const video = document.querySelector(".video-container video");
const hoverText = document.querySelector(".video-container .hover-text");

video.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  video.play();
  hoverText.classList.remove("active");
});

video.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  video.pause();
  hoverText.classList.add("active");
});


You should debug the code you're running (ideally in the browser dev tools). Note querySelector vs. querySelectorAll, if you're only grabbing the first container then it wouldn't apply to the other ones.

You should use document.querySelectorAll() to get all the videos, then loop over them to add the event listeners.

Even If i manage to get it working would I even be able to use 2 different stylesheets? cause the position of the elements needs to be different.

if main1.js is the same as main2.js then I don't see why you need to have 2 different js files for this when you can just include the same script in different pages. But judging by what I see in your code. You don't have multiple html files that you want affected by your function. You just have index.html with multiple elements. So there is no need to main1, main2, style1,style2

@SilviX: "would I even be able to use 2 different stylesheets?" - Yes, there's nothing stopping you from using two stylesheets.  Though I see no reason why you'd need to.  You seem to be under the impression that adding a second HTML element requires repeating nearly all of the code you've written.  It doesn't.  In the code shown it appears that you're simply confused between querySelector which returns the first matching element and querySelectorAll which returns a collection of all matching elements.

You can write a plugin function that takes a container selector.
Now, load the plugin into the HTML and then invoke it. Just make sure the plugin script runs before you call VideoPlugin().


.video-container > video { background: black; }

.hover-text.active { color: green; }
<!-- Load plugin -->
<!-- <script src="video-plugin.js"></script> -->
<script>
/* Plugin defined in video-plugin.js */
const VideoPlugin = (selector = '.video-container') => {
  const addListeners = (videoContainer => {
    const video = videoContainer.querySelector("video");
    const hoverText = videoContainer.querySelector(".hover-text");

    video.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      video.play();
      hoverText.classList.add("active");
    });

    video.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      video.pause();
      hoverText.classList.remove("active");
    });
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(addListeners);
};
</script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="honda/honda adv.mp4"></video>
    <div class="hover-text"><b>Autoturisme</b></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="honda/honda engine.mp4"></video>
    <div class="hover-text"><b>Motoare</b></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Execute the plugin -->
<script>
  VideoPlugin(); // The selector defaults to '.video-container'
</script>




You can use two different sets of IDs to address them in ".js" files. But I guess there may be a better and professional way to handle this scenario.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
